# Не выводит элементы BeautifulSoup Python (TripAdvisor)

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Задача состоит в парсинге данных с сайта tripadvisor. Последующего картографирования полученных данных. Проблема возникла на этапе получения данных о месте(street-address, locality) - последние строчки кода.
ОН НЕ ПОЛУЧАЕТ ДАННЫХ С САЙТА

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import json

url = "https://www.tripadvisor.ru/Attractions-g60763-Activities-New_York_City_New_York.html"


def fetch(url):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', 'https://www.tripadvisor.ru/Attractions-g60763-Activities-New_York_City_New_York.html')
    data = r.data
    return data 

def extract_data(data):
    #locate link to attraction page
    baseUrl = "https://www.tripadvisor.ru"
    website = baseUrl + data.findChildren('a')[0]['href']
    coords = extract_address(website)
    
    print("waiting 1 sec...")
    time.sleep(1)
  
    name = data.findChildren('a')[0].string.strip()
    numReviews = data.findChildren('span', 'more')[0].findChildren('a')[0].string.strip()

    print ("site name: " + name) 
    print ("number of reviews: " + numReviews) 
    print ('-------')

    return name + " | " + numReviews + "|" + str(coords['lat']) + "|" + str(coords['lng']) + "\n"

#function to open attraction page and extract adress
def extract_address(url):
    print("opening attraction page: " + url)
    page = fetch (url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    #parse HTML for address components
    street = soup.find('span',{"class":"street-address"}) 
    print("street=")
    print(street)

    
    locality = soup.find('span',{"class":"locality"})        
    print("locality=")
    print(locality)
       
    try:
        region = soup.findAll('span', 'region')[0].string.stirp()
    except Exception as e:
        region = ""
```

КОГДА ДЕЛАЮ ПРИНТ - ПОЛУЧАЮ:
street=
None
locality=
None
waiting 1 sec...
site name: Центральный парк
number of reviews: 124 546 отзывов

НЕ ПОНИМАЮ ПОЧЕМУ NONE

[image: Страничка Tripadvisor.ru]

Answer (score 0):

При каждом вызове функции fetch() запрос всегда делается к одному и тому же URL (список всех достопримечательностей):

```
r = http.request('GET', 'https://www.tripadvisor.ru/Attractions-g60763-Activities-New_York_City_New_York.html')
```

А нужно делать запрос к URL, который был передан в качестве аргумента во время вызова функции:

```
r = http.request('GET', url)
```

Проверка:

```
extract_address('https://www.tripadvisor.ru/Attraction_Review-g60763-d105127-Reviews-Central_Park-New_York_City_New_York.html')

# opening attraction page: https://www.tripadvisor.ru/Attraction_Review-g60763-d105127-Reviews-Central_Park-New_York_City_New_York.html

# street=
# <span class="street-address">59th to 110th Street</span>
# locality=
# <span class="locality">Нью-Йорк, NY 10022</span>
```

Comment: Точно
Спасибо большое!